# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mamim'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am new to Laravel framework. I keep getting this error when trying to write php artisan serve in terminal. I am not able to do somethings .Below is the info I have in my .env file.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhostphp artisan make:migration create_users_table
'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

**and my .env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mamim
DB_USERNAME=mamim
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

> I tried to clear cahce but I met always the same error;
>          SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mamim'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I'm not sure your host value in your mysql array is a good value: localhostphp artisan make:migration create_users_table, doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Its your database, try to use command line with the same database with user and password it will  give you same error.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you have a wrong password, `DB_PASSWORD=password`.

Comment: hi Pass is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhostphp artisan make:migration create_users_table'),`  to  `'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),` then try it.

Can you log into the mysql database with those credentials on the command line or in a MySQL GUI (like phpmyadmin, SequelPro, etc)?